# create a ruby enumerable from a first element, and a function to get the next element from the previous one

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

In Scala you can define a stream from its first element, and a function to get the next one from the previous one;

```
Stream.iterate(1)(x => 2 * x + 1)
```

Does something exist like this in Ruby?

Of course we can hand roll it-

```
 module Kernel
   def stream
     Enumerator.new do |y|
       that = self
       while true
         y << that
         that = yield that
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

But is it idiomatic? Is there something like this already?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this question with lazy-evaluation. You might want to check out `Enumerator::Lazy`

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Of course you have to follow the punctuation rules of whatever language you are writing in. But in the first place, no language other than English is welcomed on this site (as you also commented to some other question written in Russian).

Comment: @CarySwoveland My intention for the use of "when" here is close to "since".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking about is called an [unfold](/questions/tagged/unfold) (which is called [`Stream.iterate`](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.12.x/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html#iterate[A](start:A)(f:A=>A):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]) in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala)), or more generically, an [anamorphism](/questions/tagged/anamorphism). It is the exact category-theoretical dual of a [fold](/questions/tagged/fold) (which is called [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)) aka a [catamorphism](/questions/tagged/catamorphism).

> Is there something like this already ?

Unfortunately, there is no method in the core or standard library which performs this function.

> But is it idiomatic ?

I would probably make it a singleton method of [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) and use [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) instead of `while true`, but that's about it. Otherwise, yes, your code is pretty idiomatic.

And while we're at it, let's call it `unfold`:

```
def Enumerator.unfold(start)
  new do |y|
    loop do
      y << start
      start = yield start
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the idea of making it a singleton method of Enumerator. However, the implementation puzzles me. As far as I can see, this always produces an enumerator of Ruby Modules with Enumerator as an initial value. Is that what we want? Maybe you wanted to add a parameter for the initial value and use `that = initial_value` instead of `that = self`?

Comment: Embarrassing brainfart while refactoring OP's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know about an agreed idiomatic way of doing this. 
Since your code does not seem to produce what you like, I'll give you examples of how you could implement it.

You can use a [`Fiber`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fiber.html) to create an externally iterated unfold as follows:

```
def stream(init, &block)
  Fiber.new do 
    memo = init
    loop do
      Fiber.yield memo
      memo = block.call memo
    end
  end
end

a = stream(1){ |x| 2 * x + 1 }

a.resume  # => 1
a.resume  # => 3
a.resume  # => 7
a.resume  # => 15
```

If you prefer having an [`Enumerator::Lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) with all its superpowers, consider this:

```
def stream2(init, &block)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder| 
    memo = init
    loop do 
      yielder << memo
      memo = block.call memo 
    end 
  end.lazy
end

a2 = stream2(1){ |x| 2 * x + 1 }

a2.next  # => 1
a2.next  # => 3
a2.next  # => 7

a2.take(10).force  # => [1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023]
```

Which will behave the same as this:

```
def stream3(init, &block)
  memo = init
  (1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map{ |_| memo = block.call(memo) }
end
```

This last one is probably the most idiomatic and hides the internals of enumeration best. However, personally I dislike `stream3` because it produces numbers only to discard them.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.7 introduced [`Enumerator#produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce) which does what [George Simms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1551863/george-simms) originally asked about, AFAICT.

So the Ruby equivalent of the original Scala snippet:

```scala
Stream.iterate(1)(x => 2 * x + 1)
```

would be:

```rb
Enumerator.produce(1) { |x| 2 * x + 1 }
```

and results in:

```rb
irb> Enumerator.produce(1) { |x| 2 * x + 1 }.first(5)
=> [1, 3, 7, 15, 31]
irb> _
```

which - if you're a fan of [numbered block parameters](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/NEWS/NEWS-2.7.0#numbered-parameters-) *(another Ruby 2.7 feature)* - can also be written as:

```rb
irb> Enumerator.produce(1) { 2 * _1 + 1 }.first(5)
=> [1, 3, 7, 15, 31]
irb> _
```

Answer (score -3):

In Ruby you would use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Enumerable/inject):

`[7, 8, 9].inject(1){ |carry, item| 2 * carry + item }`

The return value of the block will be used as the next value for the carry variable.

Comment: This is the exact dual of what the OP is asking about. [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is [tag:ruby]'s [tag:fold], i.e. a [tag:catamorphism], the OP is asking about [tag:unfold] (which is called `Stream.iterate` in [tag:scala]), i.e. an [tag:anamorphism].

Comment: This doesn't address my question.

Comment: @GeorgeSimms I already apologized for getting you wrong. No need to bash me further and continue downvoting. I considered deleting this answer but decided to leave it here so noone else would make the same mistake as me. Not sure I will spend time on your questions again.